# Does the Nvidia GeForce GT 220 support Dynamic Super Resolution (DSR)?

Tags: graphics-card

I'm wondering why a few months ago (I think) I was able to use the Dynamic Super Resolution option of my GT 220 GPU. Then I replaced my GT 730. Today it seems that something went wrong or the GT 220 doesn't support DSR any more.

I want to know what it requires to support DSR, or whether there is any way to improve game resolutions similar to how DSR works.

Comment: You're wondering if the nVidia Geforce GT 220 supports DSR or not?

Comment: Yeah exatly i want to know if it requires or is there any way to improve game resolutions like dsr factor

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because graphics cards are not considered gaming-specific hardware.

Comment: Also, here's a [meta post that states graphics card questions are on topic](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9833/graphics-card-question-does-it-go-here-or-in-superuser) with 22 votes on the "yes" answer.

Comment: I concur with Frank's reasoning here but with Studoku's judgement, so I'll also VTR... though I think that it would be fine to immediately reclose with the same reasoning. The end does not justify the means.

Comment: @Studoku I quote the first line of the answer you linked to: `If the problem only occurs when running games, it'd be on topic here...`  There isn't even a *mention* of a game.  Ergo, this is not a gaming specific problem, and off-topic.

Comment: But, arguing in the opposite direction: how many non-gaming purposes does DSR have? In that sense, this question is about game-specific hardware (or the game-specificity of a function of hardware directly targeted in the question). Still, it is not the most helpful question to begin with.

Comment: '*my GT 220 GPU. Then I replaced my GT 730*' do you have 2 cards in your system?

Comment: This is much, much, much better suited for https://superuser.com/

Comment: I find it hard to separate graphics cards from their gaming-specific functionality. Dynamic Super Resolution (DSR) *is* a gaming-specific feature. Not sure how that is off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

**The nVidia Geforce GT 220 GPU does not support Dynamic Super Resolution technology**.

The [official nVidia page](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt-220/features) doesn't mention anything about it, which usually is a clear sign, and [a page listing all cards that support DSR](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/technology/dsr/supported-gpus) doesn't list the GT 220 GPU.

**There is no way to get the card to support it.** Your only option is to switch to one that *does* support it.